Reverse engineering a property for Geometric Brownian Motion
During a lecture on financial mathematics we were given a side (non-homework) question to hone the SDE solving skills.
Setting
$\left(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P},\left(\mathcal{F}_t\right)_{t \in[0, T]}\right)$ — filtered probability space. $\left(Z_t\right)_{t \in[0, T]}$ is a Brownian motion.
We are given a geometric Brownian motion: $d X_t = \mu X_t \, dt + \sigma X_t \, dZ_t$ and $X_0 \in(0, \infty).$
Problem
Let $f: \mathbb{R}_{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded and smooth function.
There exists a function $F:[0, T] \times \mathbb{R}_{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ s.t.
$$
\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}\left[f\left(X_T\right) \mid \mathcal{F}_t\right]=F\left(t, X_t\right). \tag{$\star$}
$$
Find this function.
Attempt
The property that's supposed to hold is akin to the martingale property—for that I'd be able to show that the geometric Brownian motion $X$ is a martingale with respect to the underlying Brownian motion $Z.$ But then $(\star)$ isn't obviously the exact martingale property but rather asks for something of an integrated and 2-variable relative of $f$. I don't know how to wrap/reverse engineer it to satisfy the condition.
I would appreciate any help.

I think this will work: Using Ito's formula you can write $df(X_t) = a(t, Z_t),dt + b(t, Z_t),dZ_t = dA_t + dM_t$. Then $M_t$ is probably a martingale, so $E(f(X_T) \mid \mathcal{F}_t) = E(f(X_0)) + M_t + E(A_T \mid \mathcal{F}_t)$.

This can be solved directly by using the $\mathscr{F}_t$-conditional distribution of $X_T$. You can first solve the SDE with the standard method by applying Ito to $\ln(X_t)$, obtaining the solution $X_T=X_te^{(\mu-\sigma^2/2)(T-t)+\sigma (W_T-W_t)}$, $t\leq T$. At this point, we can find the $\mathscr{F}_t$-conditional density using the fact that under the standard assumptions $W_T-W_t$ is independent of $\mathscr{F}_t$ and $X_t$ is $\mathscr{F}_t$-measurable. Let $\Phi$ be the standard normal cdf, we get:
$$\begin{aligned}
P(X_T\leq x|\mathscr{F}_t)&=P\bigg(\frac{W_T-W_t}{\sqrt{T-t}}\leq \frac{\ln(x/X_t)-(\mu-\sigma^2/2)(T-t)}{\sigma\sqrt{T-t}}\bigg|\mathscr{F}_t\bigg)\\
&=\Phi\bigg(\frac{\ln(x/X_t)-(\mu-\sigma^2/2)(T-t)}{\sigma\sqrt{T-t}}\bigg)
\end{aligned}$$
So the $\mathscr{F}_t$-conditional density is (recall $\phi$ is the standard normal pdf) by chain rule
$$\frac{d}{dx}P(X_T\leq x|\mathscr{F}_t)=\frac{1}{x\sigma\sqrt{T-t}}\phi\bigg(\frac{\ln(x/X_t)-(\mu-\sigma^2/2)(T-t)}{\sigma\sqrt{T-t}}\bigg)$$
So we conclude:
$$E[f(X_T)|\mathscr{F}_t]=\underbrace{\int_0^\infty \frac{f(x)}{x\sigma\sqrt{T-t}}\phi\bigg(\frac{\ln(x/X_t)-(\mu-\sigma^2/2)(T-t)}{\sigma\sqrt{T-t}}\bigg)dx}_{=:F(t,X_t)}$$
